# How to convert object to objects Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I need convert this object:

```
{
    "en": "[\"En1\",\"En2\"]",
    "de": "[\"De1\",\"De2\"]"
}
```

to:

```
[
    {
        "en": "En1",
        "de": "De1"
    },
    {
        "en": "En2",
        "de": "De2"
    }
]
```

Can you help me?

i tried as follows:

```js
const obj = {
  en: '["En1","En2"]',
  de: '["De1","De2"]',
};

const result = Object.entries(obj).map(([key, value]) => ({
  [key]: JSON.parse(value),
}));

console.log(result)
```

but this only returns me an array of objects and I don't know how to go ahead and create a new array with key-value matches.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const data = {
    "en": "[\"En1\",\"En2\"]",
    "de": "[\"De1\",\"De2\"]"
}

console.log(Object.values(Object.entries(data).reduce((a,[k,v])=>
  (JSON.parse(v).forEach((e,i)=>(a[i]??={})[k]=e),a),{})))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can separate your object into 2 arrays then combine them like this

```js
const obj = {
  en: '["En1","En2"]',
  de: '["De1","De2"]',
};

// Convert to array, separate them by key
let en = JSON.parse(obj.en.split(',')); 
let de = JSON.parse(obj.de.split(','));

//then combine both arrays 
const result = en.map((x,i) =>({
  en:x,
  de:de[i]
}))

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of `Array#map` and `Array#reduce` as follows. The number of items is not hard-corded, so this will work for any number of items:

```js
const 
      input = { "en": "[\"En1\",\"En2\"]", "de": "[\"De1\",\"De2\"]"},
      
      output = Object.entries(input)
        .map(([key,vals]) => JSON.parse(vals).map(v => ({[key]:v})))
        //..producing [[{"en":"En1"},{"en":"En2"}],.....]
        .reduce(
           (obj, values) => 
           obj.length === 0 ? 
             values.map(v => v) :                     //initial result: [{"en":"En1"},{"en":"En2"}]
             values.map((v,i) => ({...obj[i],...v})), //appends "de" prop to each element, ....
           []
        ); 
        
console.log( output );
```

Comment: Cool; feel free to upvote and/or accept as answer if you found this helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I've opted for a more imperative approach here. It appends objects to the `returnArray` array for each index of the parsed `values` array. If `value` matches `idx + 1` (eg `'De1'.includes(1)`), a key-value pair is initialized on the object at the current index of the `returnArray` array.

My answer relies on a lot of assumptions regarding the input. If the parsed string array elements are not in numerical order, or there are gaps in the values, `eg De3, De1, De2`, or `De1, De6`, the current solution doesn't account for it.

```js
let returnArray = [];

Object.entries(obj).forEach(pair => {
  let key = pair[0];
  let values = JSON.parse(pair[1]);

  values.forEach((_el, idx) => {
    if (!returnArray[idx]) {
      returnArray.push({});
    }

    let value = values[idx];
    if (value.includes(idx + 1)) {
      returnArray[idx][key] = values[idx];
    }
  });
});
```